# Getting Record from Firebase with AsyncTask?

Tags: android, firebase, asynchronous

I would like to get a object I have stored on fire-base with async task. i am passing an object array-list that will fill the ui with the adapter, array-list of string, books i want to retrieve, and an adapter that i would like to update the ui with, but the Im stuck with async within async and Im not sure what to do. since the firebase calls of retrieving the data is done after asynctask post-execute is done.

i would like to call this with a

```
new FetchBookWithList(bookList,bookIdList,adapter).execute()
```

some of my code:

```
protected ArrayList<Book> doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try{
            DatabaseReference bookReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("books");
            bookReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        try {
                            for (DataSnapshot books : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                if(bookListID.contains(books.child("bookID").getValue())) {
                                    Book book = books.getValue(Book.class);
                                    bookList.add(book);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.w("testing","Error: ", databaseError.toException());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bookList;
    }
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Book> s){
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            if(this.bookAdapter != null) {
                this.bookAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

my full for class code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/YKYMXMK7

Comment: There is no need to use an AsyncTask.  The Firebase APIs are all already asynchronous and don't need to be invoked from another thread.

Comment: Also bear in mind the `onDataChange` is on the UI thread so you could move the `onPostExecute` code after the for loop and do nothing in onPostExecute - but the best option is to just get rid of async task as previous comment states.

Comment: @DougStevenson how would i get about that with a one liner call, since i have to call this from multiple different classes 

Andy, thank you thats what I ended up going for now

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is here.  Just make a utility function?  There's really no need for AsyncTask here.